# Is it possible to embed and Office 365 Video inside Custom WebPart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, react

We are building an Intranet (with modern pages) in SharePoint online with SPFx 1.9.1 and React and the client wants the possiblity to embed an Office 365 Video inside a custom WebPart (via Property Pane, for example).

I have tried to embed the url -with channel and video ids included- and the iframe that Office 365 Video platform offers you to embed. But neither of them is working properly because they retrieve the 'page' (and not only the video itself).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any possiblity to embed an Office 365 Video in a custom WebPart? Is there any other public WP that I can use (I do not try the Stream WP yet in this sense)?

Sorry about any grammatical mistake I could have make and thank you for your time!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You may go thru the below article - how video can be displayed in the modern SharePoint page:

**Show a selected YouTube video:**

https://global-sharepoint.com/2019/08/18/connected-web-parts-in-sharepoint-online/